# Objective C - UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification not responding to correction selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

In my app, I have a simple textfield set up for the user's zip code while registering:

I am listening for changes to the textfield as so:

```
[self.zipCode addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

However, if the user begins typing and their ZIP code is shown as a suggestion above the keyboard, textFieldDidChange: is not called when the user taps that suggestion.

What control event should I be listening for to also include keyboard suggestions being selected?

Comment: I have created a new project and tried your code. `textFieldDidChange:` is called when you click on suggestion. Check your project again, maybe problem is from another place.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and it is working fine.

`textFieldDidChange:` not getting call that means something wrong. So please check.

So please check :

1) add `UITextFieldDelegate` in your class.

2) `self.zipCode.delegate = self;`

Note : Make sure if you have not created `self.zipCode` programmatically So you must have to check your `textfield` connection with storyboard.

If you need more help you can ask me :)